# Datepicker not working in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using .net MVC. This is my razor view of create a Bill which have a property Due Date. I want to use date picker in my code but it's not working when i use following code:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DueDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DueDate, new { id = "datepicker" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DueDate)
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { $("#datepicker").datepicker({ });});
</script>
```

So I changed the code to following then it started working but how can I pass the duedate value to controller the above code automatically attaches the due date value to object but the below code can't.

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DueDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="date" id="datepicker" class="form-control"/>   //Changing
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DueDate)
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { $("#datepicker").datepicker({ });});
</script>
```

Comment: The code in your first snippet works fine (although its unclear why you change the default `id` attribute - why not just `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DueDate)` and `$("#DueDate").datepicker();`) What errors are you getting in the browser console.

Comment: And if the 2nd code snippet is working, its because your generating the browsers HTML-5 datepicker (which is only supported in Chrome and Edge), not a jquery datepicker

Comment: You accepted a bad hack that has nothing to do with your issue. You may as well do `@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.DueDate, new { type= "date" })`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in your first snippet uses a date time picker control provided by **jQuery UI** library.To make it work you need to add a reference to the following files in this order:

1. jQuery.js
2. jQueryUI.js
3. jQueryUI.css

So your final code should look something like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

The code in your second snippet uses an HTML 5 input of type date, as was pointed out by Stephen.This automaticallly makes the input a date time picker **if it's supported by the browser**.

The reason the second snippet wasn't working is that the binding in MVC happens on the `name` property.Since your C# property is called `DueDate` you need to add `name="DueDate"` to the input element.

**Change this line:**

```
<input type="date" id="datepicker" class="form-control"/>
```

**To this:**

```
<input name="DueDate" type="date" id="datepicker" class="form-control"/>
```